# Solve too many redirect in android webview

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview

I  created an android `WebView` and open my website who server with https and authentication redirection anyway this work successfully in all of modern browsers like opera, chrome, Firefox , edge and eth but in android `WebView` i got **'too many redirect'** error
By the way when I set `WebView` cache mode to none, this error had gone, but i need the cache mode,
Any body can help me?

Comment: can you please add code with url which you are trying to load in webview.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Use this code to initialize webview and set url, it is work fine with me with all Android versions**

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private fun initWebView() {
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
    webView.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
}

private fun webViewListener() {
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
             Log.d(TAG, url)  
        }
        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest,
                                     error: WebResourceError) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
           //Error load url
        }
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            //Loading url
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

**Add this line in Manifest File**

```
   <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

[You can read more about usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)